# If loop and saving the boolean results

Tags: python, loops, boolean, conditional-statements

I have 3 different CSV files. Each has 70 rows and 430 columns. I want to create and save a boolean result file (with the same shape) that put true if the condition is met.
one file include temperature data, one wind data and one Rh data.condition is: [(t>=35) & (w>=7) & (rh<30)] 
I want the saved file to be 0 and 1 file that show in which cell the condition has been meet (1) or not (0). The problem is that results are not true! I really appreciate your help.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dft = pd.read_csv ("D:/practicet.csv",header = None)
dfrh = pd.read_csv ("D:/practicerh.csv",header = None)
dfw = pd.read_csv ("D:/practicew.csv",header = None)

result_set = []

for i in range (0,dft.shape[1]):
    t=dft[i]
    w=dfw[i]
    rh=dfrh[i]
    result=np.empty(dft.shape,dtype=bool)   
    result=result[(t>=35) & (w>=7) & (rh<30)]
    result_set = np.append(result_set,result)
np.savetxt("D:/result.csv", result_set, delimiter = ",")
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, your objective is to have a single file of 0's and 1's at the end? Or one output file for each input file?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate boolean series by testing each column of the frame. You simply then concatenate columns back into a DataFrame object.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

bool_temp = data['temperature'] > 22
bool_week = data['week'] > 5
bool_humid = data['humidity'] > 50

data_tmp = [bool_humid, bool_temp, bool_week]
df = pd.concat(data_tmp, axis=1, keys=[s.name for s in data_tmp])
```

The dummy data:

```
temperature,week,humidity
25,3,80
29,4,60
22,4,20
20,5,30
2,7,80
30,9,80
```

are written to data.csv

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot.
This is a proxy problem for yours, with random arrays from [0,100] in the same shape as your CSV.

```
import numpy as np

dft = np.random.rand(70,430)*100.
dfrh = np.random.rand(70,430)*100.
dfw = np.random.rand(70,430)*100.

result_set = []

for i in range(dft.shape[0]):
    result = ((dft[i] >= 35) & (dfw[i] >= 7) & (dfrh[i] < 30))
    result_set.append(result)

np.savetxt("result.csv", result_set, delimiter = ",")
```

The critical problem with your code is:

```
result=np.empty(dft.shape,dtype=bool)   
result=result[(t>=35) & (w>=7) & (rh<30)]
```

This does not do what you think it's doing. You (i) initialize an empty array (which will have garbage values), and then you (ii) apply your boolean mask to it. So, now you have a garbage array masked into another garbage array according to your specified boolean rules.

As an example...

```
In [5]: a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

In [6]: mask = np.array([True,False,False,False,True])

In [7]: a[mask]
Out[7]: array([1, 5])
```